# is there a way to find what this converges to? Something like $f_n(x) = f_{n-1}(x) + \frac{1}{f_{n-1}(x)}$

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have something like this:

$x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}}}} + ...$

What does this turn into as we do this infinitely many times?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the function $g(x) = x + 1/x$: $f_n(x) = g(f_{n-1}(x))$, with $f_0(x) = x$.  If you start out at any $x_0 > 0$, since $g(x) > x$ for $x > 0$ we find that the sequence is increasing and can only go to $+\infty$.  Similarly, if $x_0 < 0$ the sequence goes to $-\infty$.